# Simulink question: How was this response obtained if the input is zero?

Tags: matlab, simulink

If the input is zero here, how was the response on the right obtained? Also, how was gain block changed to equal to τ?

Please note this is a first order system with the equation dx/dt = 1/τ(u-x)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As the text right above the two figures says, "x has an initial condition". This means that the integrator is initially "charged" to a value x0 at time t=0. It is subsequently discharged by the feedback loop, and this discharging process is shown in the graph.

The gain=tau block was simply placed there to allow you to change the time constant of the integrator (depending on how you choose tau). An integrator with a different time constant is equivalent to an integrator with a different gain.

Comment: I just wanted to replicate the graph on the right. Actually tau is determined by defining it in the work space.(I didn't know that). I'm still failing to replicate the response on the right though. I'm just getting zero.

Comment: You have to add the initial condition to your integrator. If you  simulate the system without that initial condition, you will of course just get zero at the output. For example, if you simulate this using SPICE with an integration capacitor, you can add an initial charge to the cap in its spice attributes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was the key actually. Thank you so much :)...and values for tau can be input in the command window